# Proper way of doing php ajax type of call backs

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm wanting to be able to continue my knowledge with PHP.  My biggest hurdle right now is trying to better understand the way that AJAX type of calls are best used in PHP.

I know that I can do a simple Javascript type of AJAX that I found from examples with...

```
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("fileid", "somedata";
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST", "Page.php");
        ajax.send(formdata);
```

What I want to know is whats the best practice for doing a quick post back to wait for a response back from a webpage that your posting data?

For example, if I had a webpage that had a button that was to [POST] some data, but on the receiving page it's expected to take it maybe say 10 - 20 seconds before all the data completes.  Logically I would want to just throw up a "div" that says "Loading" or "Processing" until the page has fully completed.  I can't just do a normal POST because then the current page will be waiting and stuck until it fully completes.

So I would want to do an AJAX type of call to post the data, i'm assuming using the example above, and then once its completed check the results of the data sent back (or the response) and then decide what to say from there either "completed" or "failed" etc.

Whats the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: In short; do not let calls to a web server take more then a few sec, at most. Proceses like these should be ran in the background.

Comment: That's what I'm wanting to know the proper way of doing that.  I know the cURL can do background processing (i think) and the above code can do it also, but I need to know the proper way of doing it.

Comment: @eqiz you would want to add the task to a queue, the response would be a unique id to the task.  The task has a status of incomplete, do ajax calls every 5 seconds until status is complete then fetch the response using the unique id.  This is a simple solution, using SignalR would be a better choice to push the completed notification to the user browser.

Comment: @eqiz I have recommended jQuery ajax method . Please check this link http://php-tutorial-guide.blogspot.in/2014/01/json-jquery-ajax.html

Comment: @abc123 could u toss an example on how I would go about fetching the response to check?  That's the part I'm mostly confused about is HOW to do that exact thing your talking about.  Which is getting the response by either checking a .php page or something every X amount of seconds to see if it is "success" or "still processing".  I don't want to use SignalR only because I don't want to have to learn a whole new system, would rather try something simple straight forward and what you are describing sounds like a great start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an HTML page with JQuery, this will submit to the below PHP page and return a JSON payload with the ID that the next HTML + JavaScript page will use to query another PHP page.

**PHP to Add item to Queue**

```
// please don't use this exactly as this isn't safe for SQL-injection
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO tasks (1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,4,3,"this is data that was POST via the FORM using AJAX to this PHP page","incomplete")");
$id = mysqli_insert_id();
// create array to hold return values
$arr = array('id' => $id);
// return JSON to jquery
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**PHP to Query for Status of ID**

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array("SELECT status FROM tasks WHERE id = " + $id, $connection);
if($result['status'] == 'complete') {
    $arr = array('id' => $id, 'status' => $result['status'], 'payload' => $result);
}
else {
    $arr = array('id' => $id, 'status' => $result);
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

On the HTML + JavaScript page check the JSON payload status for completed...then pull back all the data

This is really a crude example but the concept is pretty simple, you are inserting data into a SQL table.  You then would make a service/CRON job to process this table and change the status when processing is completed.

The code about is more pseudo code than anything, to be clear there are a ton of other queuing systems out there that do this.

Comment: I fully understand everything here, but my question is how do i read the php response?  Would I do this on a javascript level on the page using a setTimeout or something? thats the part i'm mostly confused on.  So I have a webpage that when button is clicked it throws up a PROCESSING dialog, I do your PHP to Add Item to Que.. the processing is still showing... I know the page i would keep checking would be the QueryResponse.php kind of page (the 2nd part of code you showed).  But how would i keep checking it to see if the QueryResponse contains result of completed or w/e

Comment: @eqiz you could do a `setTimeout` that calls the QueryResponse.php via `AJAX`.  Then when the response is what you want you can either redirect them to another page that pulls the result or just pull the result and update the page.  Make sure that once the response is successful, call `clearTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple example for you. Please have a look, I think it will help you to understand

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" onchange="callajax(this.value)" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="address">Show output here</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      function callajax(s_id)
        {

            $.post("ajax.php", {id:s_id}, function(data){


                $('#address').val(data);


            });

        }
      </script>
      //your ajax.php php page
      <?php

      echo "I am here ".$_POST['id'];
      ?>
```